# Create Regional Weights

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create some weights for general country-region relations. The regions I have are overlapping, ie we might have 'Europe' and 'European Union' which are not the same. We also have the 'World' region as well.

I have a regions-country inclusion list, and a list of countries with emissions for a particular country. I'd like to find the weights according to each overlapping weight classification.

```
library(tidyverse)
RegionMap = tribble(
  ~ISO,  ~Region,
  "USA",  "NAM",
  "CAN",  "NAM",
  "FRA",  "EUR",
  "DEU",  "EUR",
  "UKR",  "EUR",
  "FRA",  "EUU",
  "DEU",  "EUU"
)

Emissions = tribble(
  ~ISO, ~Emissions,
  "USA", 1200,
  "CAN", 600,
  "FRA",  300,
  "DEU",  800,
  "UKR",  500
)

#Output:
Weights= tribble(
  ~ISO, ~Region, ~Weight,
  "USA", "NAM", 0.75,
  "CAN", "NAM", 0.25,
  "FRA",  "EUR", 0.2,
  "FRA",  "EUU", 0.25
  #etcetc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! (asking the question is 90% to answering it, I find!)

```
MergedData <- merge(RegionMap,Emissions)

Weights <- MergedData %>% group_by(Region) %>% mutate (Weight=Emissions/sum(Emissions))
```

Comment: You should click the green tick and accept your own answer.

Comment: Can't do that before 2 days have elapsed